# Javascript inserted DOM element not appearing in Safari on form submit event

Tags: javascript, html, safari

I have some javascript which listens for a form on submit event, which just displays a loader whilst a POST request takes place. It works perfectly in Chrome. But in Safari, the 'Processing...' text displays, but not the loading div.

```
window.onload = function() {
  function loadSpinner() {
    document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0].innerHTML = "Processing... <div id='loader'>Loading...</div>";
  }

  var form = document.getElementById('uploadForm');
  if (form.attachEvent) {
    form.attachEvent("submit", loadSpinner);
  } else {
    form.addEventListener("submit", loadSpinner);
  }
}
```

Comment: In case some fields don't pass the validation (e.g. 'required' attrs, etc.), safari does not fire native submit event.

Comment: @primetwig When I do a `console.log('test');` in `function loadSpinner() ...` it does display `test` in the console on submit

Comment: then I assume, div is actually being inserted, but is invisible due to some css rules. could you inspect it?

Answer (score 0):

try attaching a new div element to "container" element instead of setting html

```
$('.container').append("<div id='loader'>Loading...</div>")
```